# Python Django static css files

Tags: python, django, static

I know this is a stupid question, but I've read through the Django documentation a dozen times and read every related question on on here and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to link my template CSS to a file in my static root. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT =  'C:/Users/Chris/Dropbox/MyProject/MyProject/static/styles/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "C:/Users/Chris/Dropbox/MyProject/MyProject/static/styles",
    )
```

in the template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/styles/style.css' %}">
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',

# my url patterns here

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My guess is that either the static files code in urls.py is incorrect or the STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py, but I've tried a million combinations based on other questions on stackoverflow and nothing seems to work. I just get a 404 page not found error.

Any help is appreciated. I've spent an embarrassing amount of time on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems:

1. Your `STATIC_ROOT` directory is included in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. `STATIC_ROOT` is where the [`collectstatic` command will copy all static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/), once you are ready for deployment. You obviously don't want this path to be any where you already have static files as all files in this path are overwritten.
2. Your static url is including a path component already included in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. You have `/MyProject/static/styles` in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, this means that the `static` tag will look inside this directory for requested files.  Now you are requesting a link to `'/styles/style.css'`, and so django is looking for this file: `/MyProject/static/styles/styles/style.css` which does not exist. To fix the problem, change the static tag to `{% static 'style.css' %}`.

Comment: The main problem through all my attempts was the duplication of the '/style/' directory. Thank you so much. Such a relief to have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

try this
in settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

                         SITE_ROOT + '/templates',

)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

)
```

and in urls.py file

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                         {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.SITE_ROOT, 'templates/static')}),

                    )
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Using static path maybe more intuitive.

In settings.py declare

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# Add any additional locations of static files

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
# os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "public")
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Then in your template simply load the files